# Migration oracle to postgres accents

Tags: postgresql, oracle, diacritics, ora2pg

the original data in Oracle has accents, when I migrated the data to postgres changed the accents for special characters, How I can make the migration still the same data?

I used for the migration ora2pg.

migration the data with accents

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

Comment: What is the character encoding for both?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the Oracle client encoding (using the `NLS_LANG` environment variable) to `US7ASCII`, Oracle will silently mutilate your data by replacing characters with their unaccented versions.  You don't tell us how you invoked ora2pg, but with its default setting of `AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8` for `NLS_LANG`, that would not have happened.

Comment: In oracle use the next configuration NLS_LANGUAGE : MEXICAN SPANISH
NLS_TERRITORY: MEXICO
NLS_CHARACTERSET: WE8MSWIN1252                                                                                                    And i don't know how to configure in ora2pg

Comment: You didn't tell us your PostgreSQL server encoding, and the client encoding you used with ora2pg.

Comment: ora2pg UTF8 and postgres I don't set any. It has the default configuration.

Comment: I set AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8 at SO level, but it doesn't work